# Operator "||" not working properly in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

In the code below the second part of the filter is being executed even when the first part already returns "true". I understand that the use of the "||" operator should not perform the second part of the validation if the first is true.

```
List<data> query = new List<data>();

        query.Add(new data { name = "John", surname= "Mazi" });
        query.Add(new data { name = "Joseph", surname= "Doe" });
        query.Add(new data { name = "Paul", surname= "Allen" });
        query.Add(new data { name = "John", surname = "Doe" });


        data filters = new data { name = "John", surname = "Doe" };


        List<data> data = query.Where(x => ((x.name.Trim().ToUpper() == filters.name.Trim().ToUpper()
                                                & x.surname.Trim().ToUpper() == filters.surname.Trim().ToUpper())
                                        ||
                                             (x.name.Trim().ToUpper().Contains(filters.name.Trim().ToUpper())
                                                | x.surname.Trim().ToUpper().Contains(filters.surname.Trim().ToUpper())))).ToList();
```

In the example above it should only return one item but it keeps **returning three**.

Comment: Why `| x.surname` and not `|| x.surname`? Same with `& x.surname`

Comment: The Where statement is evaluated for each row, so for "John" it won't evaluate the second statement but then it starts over for Joseph and evaluates the first one (which is false) and then the second one (which will be true).

Comment: How exactly did you deterime the second part of the filter is being executed if the first part (left side) of `||` is already true? Me thinks you made some mistake during debugging, or just "creatively" interpreted the result you got, and made a wrong conclusion in the process...

Comment: I think you want `&&` and not `||` if you want to return only `John Doe`

Comment: `logical OR` isn't the same as `conditional logical OR` here is the documentation for both: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators

Comment: As written, the expression is supposed to find three items and it finds. Rewrite your condition as a proper function and test it properly.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren If the validation occurs independently for each line here it makes sense to execute the second part.

Comment: You give us some code that doesn't do what you want, but you don't say what you want instead. Consider to edit the question and write in words your requirements: which data should pass the filter?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse The problem is that it is returning three records and from the code I expected it to return only one. But I already understood in the comments above the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of the or operator is correct, but you have to take into consideration, that your validation will be executed for every entry inside the list. With this in mind, if you go through the validation, you will see why in this case three datasets get returned.
For readability and ease of use, i would split the validation into two in your case:

```
List<data> data = query.Where(x => ((x.name.Trim().ToUpper() == filters.name.Trim().ToUpper()
                                                & x.surname.Trim().ToUpper() == filters.surname.Trim().ToUpper()).ToList();
//If no exact matches, get datasets where name/ surname is contained
if(!data.Any())
{
    data = query.Where(x => (x.name.Trim().ToUpper().Contains(filters.name.Trim().ToUpper())
                                                || (x.surname.Trim().ToUpper().Contains(filters.surname.Trim().ToUpper())).ToList();
}
```

This would first try to return every exact match and if none, every dataset where the name or surname is contained.